# How to define width by percentage in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a view with a border around it that is centered and fills 80% of the screen.  I have come up with this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <View style={{flex: .1}} />
  <View style={{flex: .8, borderWidth: 2}} />
  <View style={{flex: .1}} />
</View>
```

which works, but seems awfully verbose.

Is there a better (more succinct) way to create a view that is a certain percentage of the screen width and centered in the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Starting from React Native version 0.42 we now have a full percentage support for `width`, `height` , `padding` and so on, see the full list and examples here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11

**Old method:**

Consider using [`Dimensions`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/dimensions.html), like:

```
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
```

and then in element's style:

```
width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 100 * 80,
```

Working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/4pdwlg

Comment: I was able to `import { Dimensions } from "react-native"` - not sure if something changed or if there is just more than one way to import.